# Working with MySQL on large projects - multiple databases or not?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

Here at work we are working on a project that's growing at a decent speed, and we are currently planning on how to expand even further in 2018.

We have had one tech-guy at our office telling us a bit about his own experiences working with other companies on large projects that use PHP + MySQL.

I'm the only developer on our project, so I have no one else to debate with or ask questions, when I am confused - so I'll try here.

This tech-guy asked me on how our database was built, and I told him MySQL. He asked if there was one database holding all tables or multiple databases with each having their own respective tables (e.g. databases grouped by task/feature etc.), and I replied just one database with all tables in the project.

He then recommended to split my tables up to multiple databases. Is this a bad idea?

We run a tournament platform with different game formats like group stages, single- and double-elimination playoffs and more to come. The group stage features are on the way, and he suggested creating a separate database called "tournament_groups" and put all relevant tables inside this.

**NB:** I use Laravel 5.4 for development with the Eloquent ORM.

So in summary: multiple databases with a few tables in each, or one database with all tables within?

Comment: I think it is easier working with one database. And not have to connect to another. This is my opinion.

Comment: What reason did your colleague put forward for using multiple databases?

Comment: @Strawberry, I would assume the reason to be if the tables were to be filled up with millions of entries that would consume too much data, which is why he wanted me to split it up... I am not too sure though, as I am confident MySQL is able to handle this.

Comment: I wonder if your colleague also explores Stack Overflow? `;-)`

Comment: Tuna fish seems a more plausible explanation

Comment: The number of rows is irrelevant when considering the number of databases.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer is not so obvious. There are multiple things to consider:

1) Ease of development - in fact it's much easier to have single database - you run migrations only into this single database, if you want to verify something in live database you verify only single database but you need to add for multiple models conditions as for example `where('company_id', 5)` and you need to be very careful not to allow people from one company to access data from other company

2) Security or business/legal demands - in some cases because of legal things each client should have separate database. For example if admin of company should get access to database you can easily get him access to his company database but you cannot give him access to database which hold multiple companies.

3) Performance - depending on how many data you expect because of performance reasons it might be better to have separate database for each client if you expect millions on rows in tables

I was working in both scenarios, and for me as a developer it's much more convenient to have single database but as I said in some cases the only option might be having multiple databases.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I do not expect to have millions of rows on these tables. If we fast forward 5 years, perhaps I would suggest a couple hundred-thousands maybe. Would sticking with one database be the preferred way then in your own opinion? I agree it's convenient to have everything in one database.

Comment: For me if 2 and 3 are not so important, I would prefer having single database

Comment: Thanks, I will keep these things in mind for the future.

Comment: Point 2: it's easy to grant MySQL user prvileges to only access certain tables. Takes a little bit of working in PHP to establish which database  connection user should be used, and some backend setting up in MySQL (to make the user) but it's easy enough just a little time-consuming to set up.

Comment: @Martin But if data of multiple clients are in single table it won't be so easy

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek then it would be down to the PHP system to allow or deny access to certain records *within* any particular table

Answer (score 0):

I think that your colleague is talking about a [microservice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microservices) architecture where you split not only the databases, but you split the whole application into a set of independent components. It's not just splitting a database.

An [article](https://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html) by Martin Fowler might be a good starting point.